# strlen on 2 strings

Tags: php

```
if (strlen($title) && strlen($message) > 3)
```

This returns true if $title is over 3 chars, I only want it to return true if BOTH is.
Whats the correct way? Tried a bunch. FNYS.

Help please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if ((strlen($title) > 3) && (strlen($message) > 3))

I do see what you're shooting for, but it's not often supported. In general, each chunk of the "if" test is self-standing -- I like to add extra parentheses, just to make things clearer to scan.

So your original test boiled down to "if(strlen($title))" and "if(strlen($message) > 3)".

Comment: Clear and straight forward. I like it.

Comment: Iagree...with the neatness of the solution

Answer (score 5):

if (min(strlen($title), strlen($message)) > 3)